# What are common uses for the system (3) command?

Tags: c, standard-library, c89

I came across [the command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) while reading the famous [C Language Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) (1988). Is the command commonly used today?

From the book (section 7.8.4):

> The function *system(char *s)* executes the command contained in the
>   character string s, then resumes execution of the current program. The
>   contents of s depend strongly on the local operating system. As a
>   trivial example, on UNIX systems, the statement
>   **system("date");**
>   causes the program *date* to be run ...

I was under the impression that fork-and-exec is the main way to run another program from the current one...

Comment: Fork/exec is not standard C, not does it do the same thing

Comment: On unix systems, `system(cmd)` is effectively `fork()` + `execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", cmd, (char *)NULL)` + `waitpid()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system` it **the** function from the standard C library that allows a C program to invoke an external (meaning OS level) command.

(Almost) everything is in the above sentence: the function is standard C, meaning that is is supported by any conformant implementation. But what OS does is err... just OS dependant.

It should the prefered way for writing portable programs (because it is standard C) but unfortunately:

1. not all OS support same commands and/or same syntax
2. it is known to have some caveats on most systems

The latter part is related to security: many OS (at least all I know) have a configurable *path* where a command is searched, and in that case the `system` function does use that path. The problem is that by changing the path, the program can invoke in reality a command that is not the one intended by the programmer, if someone managed to install a different command with same name in a place they control, and also managed to change the path.

This is the reason why `system` is generally frowned upon and careful programmers only rely on lower level system dependant functions like fork+exec on Unix like or CreateProcess on Windows, or alternatively use absolute paths for the commands called from `system`. But then you need a rather complex configuration way to adapt that absolute path to various systems...

Comment: Ah, forgot about Windows (and all the none Unix like OS's that use C). They would definitely have their own preferred way to run programs.

Comment: I think the purpose of the `system` command was to allow for programs to perform arbitrary actions by means of an OS-specific string received from the command line or a text file.  The text file or command-line arguments would need to be adjusted based upon the target OS, but the C source text would not.